# Unable to put switch statement inside the foreach loop in mvc 4

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

This is my controller where i have array of strings and through `ViewData` I am sending data to view.

```
[HttpGet]
public PartialViewResult GetMeataDataDetails(int id)
{
    tr_upld_content upld1 = new tr_upld_content();
    string[] contentlabel = db.tr_doc_content.Where(x => x.doc_typeid == id).Select(x=>x.doc_contenttypelabel).ToArray();
    ViewData["passedarray"] = contentlabel;
    string[] ctrltype = db.tr_doc_content.Where(x => x.doc_typeid == id).Select(x => x.doc_ctrltype).ToArray();
    ViewData["ctrltype"] = ctrltype;
    string[] fieldtype = db.tr_doc_content.Where(x => x.doc_typeid == id).Select(x => x.doc_fieldtype).ToArray();
    return PartialView(upld1);
}
```

this is my view code.

```
@model C3KYCSystem.tr_upld_content
<h2>GetMeataDataDetails</h2>
@foreach (string lbl in ViewData["passedArray"] as string[])
{
    <br />
    <tr>@lbl</tr>
}
@foreach (string crl in ViewData["ctrltype"] as string[])
{
    switch(ViewData["ctrltype"].ToString())
    {
        case "textbox":
            <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.upld_contentvalue)</td>
            break;
    }     
}
```

`Viewdata["ctrltype"]` contains values such as textbox, multiline textbox etc. if it is textbox I want to get editor template and so on. I want to iterate through each array of string and check inside the switch and if it matches then render accordingly. At this time switch is not executing.

Comment: You can have as many loops as you want. But FGS, use a view model and populate it in the controller rather that using `ViewData` so you can strongly bind to your model.

Comment: I have array of strings in my controller. With each array of strings i want to perform different operations. If i put switch i am struggling otherwise it works fine.

Comment: Your question was about a problem with multiple `foreach` loops. Are you now saying the problem is with the `switch` statements?

Comment: Yes Multiple for loops working fine if i remove switch from second for loop. I i figure out now problem is with switch statement

Comment: Then edit your question including the title and explanation and show the relevant code and explain what you expect an what is actually happening

Comment: How can i change question? where i can do this?

Comment: Click on the edit link and the bottom of the question (or just delete this and start over)

Comment: `switch(ViewData["ctrltype"].ToString())` would not work (add a `<div>ViewData["ctrltype"].ToString()</div>` to understand. I assume you want `switch(crl)`

Comment: yes i want switch(crl) and its working now. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Where i can mark this question as answered?

Comment: I'll add an answer shortly :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change

```
switch(ViewData["ctrltype"].ToString())
```

to

```
switch(crl)
```

to access each item in the loop